# Galvanic corrosion in a non-corroding environment

Tags: materials, corrosion

If we submerge a welded structure of, for example, Duplex (1.4462) and Stainless Steel (1.4301) in water, which is normally not a threat for either of these materials alone, do we see corrosion in the Stainless Steel due to galvanic coupling? Is there an electric potential difference between these materials in water or does it depend on the substance they are submerged in?

I can see that in a corroding environment where the materials would trade electrons with the environment, then the electrons lost by the more noble material (Duplex) would be replaced by electrons from the less noble material (Stainless Steel).

Comment: I'd be more worried about the welding material interacting with either material.

Comment: It depends on the water chemistry,and possibly other factors.